# 403 Forbidden with Log4Net and MVC5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, log4net

So I followed [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/823247/How-to-use-Apache-log-net-library-with-ASP-NET-MVC) tutorial to add logging to my project. Locally everything works fine, but when I deploy it to my staging environment and try to even visit the root page of the site I get a `403.14 Forbidden` error saying that I need to enable *Directory Browsing*. I read somewhere that *log4net* uses a different user account to log and that could be causing issues. I was also thinking that it could be due to the location I am logging. I was hoping someone else had experienced this and could point out a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't with your code or Log4Net, it's with your hosting environment's default settings. Change the directory of the log file that is being written to a directory where you actually have rights, or change the access on the directory to which you are writing... Sounds like you're on a shared hosting server, and you usually need to manually enable whether or not a directory can have write access (ie: GoDaddy, etc). I've had this a few times and it was simple as that. This is why it was working locally (you have permissions to your own machine) and not once it was deployed.

Comment: We have out own server but I just took it over from another person so I was unfamiliar. This did the trick though...thanks a bunch